# Поиск параметра в строке и вывод его значения

Tags: python, python-3.x

После выполнения запроса получаю строку параметров, среди которых есть следующие:

```
name="Bob" job=artist age="35" date=2018.12.21
```

Как вывести значения параметров в таком виде:

```
Имя - Bob
Работа - artist
Возраст - 35
Дата - 2018.12.21
```

Пробую через re.findall с поиском по словам name= job= и т.д., но не получаю то, что нужно (не могу вывести значение без кавычек и дата обрезается после года).

Строку получаю через ssh:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('grep -rw '/root/list.txt' -e 'Bob'')
data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
print(data)
b'name="Bob" job=artist age="35" town=Chehov date=2018.12.21 active="yes"\n'
```

Comment: Как именно выглядит строка, можете показать пример?

Comment: Заодно можно подробнее рассказать, как именно вы её получаете и откуда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = b'name="Bob" job=artist age="35" date=2018.12.21 active="yes"\n'
data = data.decode()

values = {k: v for (k, v) in
          (item.replace('"', '').split('=') for item in data.split())
          }

print('Имя - {}'.format(values['name']))
print('Работа - {}'.format(values['job']))
print('Возраст - {}'.format(values['age']))
print('Дата - {}'.format(values['date']))
```

Comment: я бы заменил print('Имя - {}'.format(values['name'])) на print(f'Имя - {values['name']})

Comment: @garrythehotdog, мне тоже очень нравится синтаксис f-строк. Но, версия 3.6+ пока далеко не у всех стоит, так что я бы не пихал по умолчанию синтаксис из этих версий :)

Comment: @Александр ваш пример работает. У меня ошибки: b'name="Bob" job=artist age="35" town=Spb date=2018.12.21 active="yes"\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    (item.replace('"', '').split('=') for item in data.split())
  File "c:\test.py", line 10, in <dictcomp>
    values = {k: v for (k, v) in
  File "c:\test.py", line 11, in <genexpr>
    (item.replace('"', '').split('=') for item in data.split())
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @Ven0m, у вас байтовая строка. Такие вещи стоит указывать в вопросе сразу. Чтобы привести байтовую строку к обычной, вы можете использовать метод decode. Я поправил мой ответ, теперь он должен работать для вас.